# Parsing DateTime String from CSV File As Event Timestamp

Tags: csv, timestamp, etl, wso2-streaming-integrator

**Using WSO2 SP, my app reads lines from the following CSV file:**

```
20170801 000001237,1.321420,1.321510,0
20170801 000001487,1.321440,1.321530,0
20170801 000001737,1.321450,1.321530,0
20170801 000001987,1.321440,1.321530,0
```

**The first column is a timestamp string that needs to be parsed to timestamp the event:**

```
yyyyMMdd hhmmssfff
```

**, where fff are milliseconds**

**my current app looks like this:**

```
@App:name('ReceiveAndCount')
@App:description('count events in csv file')
@source(type = 'file', 
    mode='line',
    tailing='false',
    file.uri = "file:/Users/A/Desktop/siddhi/wso2sp-4.4.0/data/DAT_ASCII_GBPUSD_T_201708.csv", 
    action.after.process='NONE',
        @map(type = 'csv', header='false', delimiter = ",",
        @attributes(
        dateTime = '0',
        bid='1',
        ask='2',
        ignore='3'  ) ))

define stream csvGBPUSDstream (dateTime string, bid double, ask double, ignore int);

@sink(type = 'log', priority='info')
define stream TotalCountStream (totalCount long);

-- Count the incoming events
@info(name = 'query1')
from csvGBPUSDstream 
select count() as totalCount
insert into TotalCountStream;
```

**Any guidance on parsing the date string in the first column as event timestamp is greatly appreciated**

Comment: Using the following, I parse the dateTime string, however the timestamp resulting from from parse is treated as data value, not a time index necessary for calculating time windows. Siddhi attaches an event timestamp. How do I get Siddhi to use parsed timestamp as index?       ,                                                                                                   .                       @info(name = 'Parse Timestamp')
from csvGBPUSDstream
select time:timestampInMilliseconds(dateTime,'yyyyMMdd HHmmssSSS') as timestamp, bid, ask
insert into indexedGBPUSDstream;

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in using the #window.externalTime() function

```
@App:name('CsvParseDateTime')
```

@App:description('parse timestamp string from csv file')

@source(type = 'file', mode = "line", tailing = "false", file.uri = "file:/Users/A/Desktop/siddhi/wso2sp-4.4.0/data/DAT_ASCII_GBPUSD_T_201708.csv", action.after.process = "NONE", 
    @map(type = 'csv', header = "false", delimiter = ",", 
        @attributes(dateTime = "0", ask = "2", ignore = "3", bid = "1")))
define stream csvGBPUSDstream (dateTime string, bid double, ask double, ignore int);

@sink(type = 'log', priority = "info")
define stream fiveSecRangeStream (timestamp long, fiveSecRange double);

-- streat to parse dateTime string to millisecond time that can be used as index for time windows
--time:timestampInMilliseconds(date.value,date.format) yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
@info(name = 'Parse Timestamp')
from csvGBPUSDstream 
select time:timestampInMilliseconds(dateTime, 'yyyyMMdd HHmmssSSS') as timestamp, bid, ask 
insert into indexedGBPUSDstream;

-- external window time (timestamp in event stream)
from indexedGBPUSDstream#window.externalTime(timestamp,5 Sec)
select timestamp, max(bid)-min(bid) as fiveSecRange
insert into fiveSecRangeStream; --  for all-events ;

Answer (score 0):

Running wso2sp-editor in docker via the following command, with volume switch to allow reading local data file:

```
docker run -it -p 9390:9390 -v /Users/A/Desktop/wso2sp-editor-docker-data:/home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.4.0/data/ --name editor wso2/wso2sp-editor:4.4.0
```

Finally the app code:

```
 @App:name('CsvParseDateTime')
```

@App:description('parse timestamp string from csv file')
--abrakadabra
@source(type = 'file', mode = "line", tailing = "false", file.uri = "file://home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.4.0/data/DAT_ASCII_GBPUSD_T_201708.csv", --"file:/Users/A/Desktop/siddhi/wso2sp-4.4.0/data/DAT_ASCII_GBPUSD_T_201708.csv", action.after.process = "NONE", 
    @map(type = 'csv', header = "false", delimiter = ",", 
        @attributes(dateTime = "0", ask = "2", ignore = "3", bid = "1")))
define stream csvGBPUSDstream (dateTime string, bid double, ask double, ignore int);

@sink(type = 'log', priority = "info")
define stream fiveSecRangeStream (timestamp long, fiveSecRange double);

-- streat to parse dateTime string to millisecond time that can be used as index for time windows
--time:timestampInMilliseconds(date.value,date.format) yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
@info(name = 'Parse Timestamp')
from csvGBPUSDstream 
select time:timestampInMilliseconds(dateTime, 'yyyyMMdd HHmmssSSS') as timestamp, bid, ask 
insert into indexedGBPUSDstream;

-- external window time (timestamp in event stream)
from indexedGBPUSDstream#window.externalTime(timestamp,5 Sec)
select timestamp, max(bid)-min(bid) as fiveSecRange
insert into fiveSecRangeStream; --  for all-events ;